# Can't access DOM from SCM Music Player

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js, audio-player

I am building a website using SCM Music Player (an open source web player), and I would like to use the "finish" callback to modify my DOM when the music stops. I can access this callback and execute a "console.log()", but I can't access DOM... I've noticed that this script uses Knockout library, but I don't know how it works and if it is necessary... Here is my code from scm.js:

```
finish = function(){
    //repeat one start again, otherwise next song
    if(repeatMode()==2) start();
    else {
        console.log('Next son de scm.js :');
        var div = ko.observable($('#ajouterSon').attr('role'));

        console.log('Div: ' + div);

        next();
    }
};
```

And the kind of changes I do when I play a song :

```
$('.musiqueLink').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('clic musique - last id = ' + lastidmusique);
  event.preventDefault();
  if(lastidmusique != null)
    document.getElementById('row'+lastidmusique).setAttribute("class", "row");
  document.getElementById('row'+$(this).attr('data-idmusique')).setAttribute("class", "row highlighted");
  SCM.play({title:$(this).attr('data-titre'),url:$(this).attr('data-lien')});
  lastidmusique = $(this).attr('data-idmusique');
});
```

The dom which contains 'ajouterSon' :

```
<body style=" background-image: url('imgs/backgrnd.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed;">
<div id="ajouterSon" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h1 class="text-center">Ajouter un son</h1>
          <?php

          ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" id="ajoutSon">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" title="Titre du son" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Titre" id="titre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" title="Auteur du son" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Artiste" id="artiste">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="genre">Style</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="selectpicker" multiple  id="genre">
                  <?php
                    $genres = $mysqli->query("SELECT idgenre, nom FROM GENRE");
                    while($row = $genres->fetch_array())
                      $rows[] = $row;
                    mysqli_free_result($genres);
                    foreach($rows as $row)
                    {
                      $styles = $mysqli->query("SELECT idstyle, nom FROM STYLE WHERE GENRE = ".intval($row['idgenre']));
                      while($rowStyles = $styles->fetch_array())
                        $rowsStyles[] = $rowStyles;
                      echo "<optgroup label=\"".$row['nom']."\">";
                      foreach ($rowsStyles as $rowStyles) 
                        echo "<option value=\"".$rowStyles['idstyle']."\">".$rowStyles['nom']."</option>";
                      echo "</optgroup>";
                      mysqli_free_result($styles);
                      unset($rowsStyles);
                    }
                    unset($rows);
                  ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" title="Décris ton son" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Description" id="description">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="url" title="Lien Youtube/Soundcloud" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Lien Youtube/Soundcloud" id="lien">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" id="submit">Ajouter</button>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Annuler</button>
          </div>    
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
</body>
```

I precise that I have placed my include balise for the JS just above the end of the body.

Thank you for your help,
Théo

Comment: `ko.observable($('#ajouterSon').attr('role'))` this would not give you your dom. if you are just targetting just the DOM and nothing related to observable, then just executer this `var div = $('#ajouterSon').attr('role');`

Comment: Yes sorry about that, that's what I was trying to do but then I tried with Knockout and forgot to ctrl+z before pasting my code ... So it doesn't work neither ...

Comment: If your expecting the html/text content of the element `$('#ajouterSon')`,then   execute  `$('#ajouterSon').html()` or `$('#ajouterSon').text()`. it would be good if you post the generated html structure here

Comment: That isn't  working at all ... .html(), .text() or .attr() return "undefined ... What do you mean by the generated html structure ?

Comment: I meant the Dom structure

Comment: Of th whole page ? Because I used 'ajouterSon' as an example, but that is not the final item I want to treat ...

Comment: without that its difficult to verify  whether the element with id selector which your trying to access is available or not. try posting the Dom which is relevant for your issue, i mean which contains  this element `ajouterSon`

Comment: Yes I have added it now

Comment: Are you saying that `$(#ajouterSon).html()` is yielding nothing ??? I really dont see a reason why it would not work

Comment: Yeah that's it, I don't know but the script where is the callback is already called from the script that I call in my index (script-ception ^^)